# Не работает функция explode. Строка должна обрезаться по подстроке, но этого не происходит

Tags: php, строки

У меня есть функция, в которую передаются строки

```
function getAnswer($block, $num, $start, $end) {
  $start .= ' ';
  $end .= ' '; //Добавили пробелы к концу (A. )
  //$answer = stristr($block, $end, true); //Обрезали лишние варианты ответа
  $string = explode($end, $block);
  $answer = explode($start, $string[0]);
  if (!isset($answer[1])) {
    echo "<br/>Проблема с вариантами вопроса {$num}<br/>";
    echo "STRING [режем по |{$end}|, берем 0 элемент]<br/>";
    var_dump($string);
    echo "<br/><br/>ANSWER [режем по |{$start}|, берем 1 элемент]<br/>";
    var_dump($answer);
    echo "<br/><br/>Если все ок, попробуйте заменить варианты ответа |{$start}| или |{$end}| на английские!";
    exit;
  }

  else {
    return str_replace('%2A', '', urlencode($answer[1]));
  }
}
```

В ответе я получаю

> Проблема с вариантами вопроса 90 STRING [режем по |B. |, берем 0
>   элемент] array(1) { [0]=> string(596) "У хворого 15-ти років
>   концентрація глюкози натще – 4,8 ммоль/л, через годину після цукрового
>   навантаження – 9,0 ммоль/л, через 2 години – 7,0 ммоль/л, через 3
>   години – 4,8 ммоль/л. Ці показники характерні для такого захворювання:
>   A. Прихований цукровий діабет B. Цукровий діабет II типу C. Цукровий
>   діабет I типу D. - E. Хвороба Іценко-Кушинга " }
>
> ANSWER [режем по |A. |, берем 1 элемент] array(1) { [0]=> string(596)
>   "У хворого 15-ти років концентрація глюкози натще – 4,8 ммоль/л, через
>   годину після цукрового навантаження – 9,0 ммоль/л, через 2 години –
>   7,0 ммоль/л, через 3 години – 4,8 ммоль/л. Ці показники характерні для
>   такого захворювання: A. Прихований цукровий діабет B. Цукровий діабет
>   II типу C. Цукровий діабет I типу D. - E. Хвороба Іценко-Кушинга " }
>
> Если все ок, попробуйте заменить варианты ответа |A. | или |B. | на
>   английские!

То есть оно должно разбить на массив по "B. " строку, в которой содержится такая же "B. ".
Я уверен, что это абсолютно одинаковые подстроки. Т.к. при копировании и поиске в редакторе они одинаковые, ну и браузер говорит то же
[image: Поиск по B.]

[image: Поиск по B.]

Comment: Какой ожидаемый результат должен быть? Приведите пример входных данных.

Comment: ну дак попробовали заменить A и B на английские? или наоборот на русские, очевидно, строки эти не равны

Comment: Я же показал, что даже для браузера они абсолютно равны. Поиск их воспринимает как одинаковые символы. + исходные данные скопировал. Но почему-то exploid их воспринимает как разные.

Я даже выводил эти данные по символьно, сравнивал коды символов. Абсолютно одинаковые. А exploid не берет их)